# mat-table first column is taking all the remaining space

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material-table

`mat-table` is taking extra width for first column even when all the columns has same css. This is how it shows

[image]

You can see the `First Name` column is taking all the extra width remaining after all the columns

I want either all the columns to take equal width or the last column take all the remaining space not the first column.

This is the table definition

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="gridDatasource" class="body-text" matSort #empTbSort="matSort">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item?.firstName}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item?.lastName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item?.email}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fundHouseName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Fund House </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item?.fundHouseShortName}} - {{item?.fundHouseFullName}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fundName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Fund </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item?.fundShortName}} - {{item?.fundFullName}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="emailConfirmed">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Email Confirmed </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item.emailConfirmed?'Yes':'No'}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="isActive">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item.isActive?'Active':'In-Active'}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="folioNo">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-5 fw-semibold" mat-sort-header> Folio No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.folioNo}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions" stickyEnd>
      <th mat-header-cell [hidden]="!featurePermissionService.canEditInvestor" *matHeaderCellDef
        class="column-5  fw-semibold"> </th>
      <td mat-cell [hidden]="!featurePermissionService.canEditInvestor" *matCellDef="let item">
        <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Edit" (click)="openEditDialog(item)">edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="gridColumns">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: gridColumns;">
    </tr>
    <tr class="mat-row no-data-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td *ngIf="loading" class="mat-cell-load" [attr.colspan]="gridColumns.length">
        <div class="spinner">
          <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td *ngIf="!loading" style="text-align: center;" class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="gridColumns.length">
        No data matching the filter.
      </td>
    </tr>
 </mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
```

And this is the css I am using

```
.mat-table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.mat-cell,
.mat-header-cell {
  word-wrap: initial;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-break: unset;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Any leads?